# how to track emails in google analytics?

Tags: email, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So i want to track my emails sent from my web application, i follow this [tutorial][1]

but i didn't have any result, this is my image url that i put it into my email template :

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=TID_ID&cid=CID_key&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=open_email&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=Test_Newsletter
```

in my google analytics i create an account with my web application address dev.mylittlebiz.fr but my emails send it via mailGun via this address mylittlebiz.fr.

so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Comment: This URL seems correct (assuming `tid` & `cid` are valid). I know you said you used this URL as the "src" for an "img" inside your mail template, but could you provide the complete <img> tag you used?